# Need to have the source created with Rmarkdown otherwise error message

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hello StackOverflow community,

I have been trying over the last few weeks using R Markdown to Knit HTML file.
While it use to run smoothly the previous time, over the last week I keep on getting the following error

```
Quitting from lines 43-92 (Vizualisation.Rmd) 
Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : 
  object 'processed.feedback' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> %>% -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

The thing is that my source 'processed.feedback' is loaded within my Global environment. But is not created with the .rmd but before in a script file.

If I do the wrangling as well in the same Rmarkdown the it works fine (no error). But I would love to keep the wrangling part in a separate file.

Any suggestion.
Thanks in advance for your feedback and help!
If you are at the Rstudio conference - enjoy!

Comment: Here are two options I can think of to solve this: run your wrangling code in .rmd using the `source` function (e.g. `source(my_directory/my_wrangling_code.R)` or save `processed.feedback` as a .csv (or whatever is most reasonable for the data) and then use a `read` function to pull it in.

Comment: Thanks bouncyball - will lookinto it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual model is that R Markdown files do not see objects that are in your workspace:  they start with a blank workspace, so that anyone can reproduce the computation.  (There are ways to work in an existing workspace, but you shouldn't use them.)

If it takes too long to create an object in the Rmd code, then there are at least two options:  turn on caching (so it only happens when necessary), or save the object in a separate file using `save()` and load it in your document using `load()`.  Remember to distribute the save file along with the `.Rmd` file if you want to give this document to someone else.

Comment: Thanks - I am not able to upvote your answer as my reputation is not high enough. But it all makes sense now. Much appreciated!